# Washing cuts in Mexico

Tags: health, tap-water

I know you aren't supposed to drink the tap water in Mexico.

What about washing a cut with tap water?

If I shower, tap water will get into the cut.

Answer (score 5):

An open cut can easily be infected even without showering. Apply antibacteriological ointment and a plaster in any case. If showering, make that a waterproof plaster.

If you want to wash a cut, use a sterile wipe.

Comment: Good general advice but it doesn't actually answer the question. If tap water *does* inadvertently come in contact with the wound, should the Asked re-apply the antibacterial cream and bandage, in light of other warnings/restrictions re water quality in Mexico? (For example, I would follow your advice even here in the US, but I also wouldn't worry if some tap water got onto the wound. Alternatively the Asker might not have had immediate access to a first aid kit.)